In Swagger UI integer values are assigned the maximum value
When we upgrade OpenAPI version in our project from 3.0.3 to 3.1.0 then all integers in request body example are assigned the maximum value in request body preview. It's kinda weird to see every integer in Swagger UI equals 9007199254740991 instead of 0 as it was before in every Swagger UI. Is any possibility to set default value to 0 in every request body globally?
The problem is shown on screenshot here:

Current implementation is here:
@Bean
  public OpenAPI customizeOpenAPI() {
    final String securitySchemeName = "bearerAuth";
    return new OpenAPI()
        .addSecurityItem(new SecurityRequirement().addList(securitySchemeName))
        .components(new Components().addSecuritySchemes(securitySchemeName,
            new SecurityScheme()
                .name(securitySchemeName)
                .type(SecurityScheme.Type.HTTP)
                .scheme("bearer")
                .bearerFormat("JWT")))
        .info(new Info().title("Project example API")
            .summary("Api Documentation")
            .version("3.1.0")
            .license(new License().name("Apache 2.0").identifier("Apache-2.0")
                .url("https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html")))
        .openapi("3.1.0");
}

Tried to create an issue in Swagger GitHub repo but we have not get answer from someone. I know there is possibility to do that using annotations or downgrading Swagger. Is there any possibility to keep OpenAPI 3.1.X and set default value to 0?

Known issue: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/9816

@Helen This issue opened by my teammate. I decided to ask here cause we didn't receive any answers there.

I'd be curious to see your schema definitions. The code you posted there doesn't correlate to the issue you're having
